# Lookup user profile based on email address - via LinkedIn API

Tags: linkedin-api

I would like to know if it is possible (and how if so) to find a LinkedIn profile based on email address (or phone number) via LinkedIn API. We have plan to match our clients with their LinkedIn profile if it is possible.

I have found similar functionality here: https://www.fullcontact.com/developer/docs/person,
but this is paid service.

I would like to get this for free via LinkedIn API.
Thanks for advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like it is available as a parameter.

https://developer-programs.linkedin.com/documents/people-search-api